Node.js Express application not logging MongoDB connection status
I'm developing a Node.js Express application that connects to a MongoDB database. Despite implementing logging in my code, the application does not log anything related to the MongoDB database connection status.
Expected Behavior vs. Actual Behavior:
I expect my application to log "MongoDB connected successfully" when it establishes a connection to the MongoDB database. However, no database connection-related logs appear in the console.
Steps Taken:

Checked MongoDB server status and ensured it's running.
Verified MongoDB connection URL and database name in config/connection.js.
Reviewed console output for any relevant errors or warnings.

how can fix this?
package.json:
 "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^7.1.3",
    "hbs": "^4.2.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "mongodb": "^6.8.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.4"
  }



config/connection.js : 
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const state = {
    db:null
}

module.exports.connect = function(done){
    const url='mongodb://localhost:27017'
    const dbname='shopsy'


    MongoClient.connect(url,(err,data)=>{
        if(err) return done(err)

            state.db=data.db(dbname)
            done()
})

}
module.exports.get= function(){
    return state.db
}

app.js :

const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const adminsRouter = require('./routes/admin');
const db = require('./config/connection'); // Importing the updated database connection module

const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs.engine({
    extname: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'layout'), // Fixed directory path
    partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'partials') // Fixed directory path
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Connect to the database
db.connect((err)=>{
    if(err) console.log('connection error'+err);
    else console.log("database connected");
  })

// Routes
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/admin', adminsRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.error("Error handler middleware reached:", err.message);
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;       


I have posted my answer.Please check and let me know your feedback.

The problem is that when you use module.exports.connect & module.exports.get it will overwrite the entire module.exports each time resulting in only one property being exported.
Try this for config/connection.js.
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let _DB;  

//putting the MongoDB connection code in an arrow function
const MongoConnection = (callback) =>{

    //creating connection to MongoDB database with connect() method which returns a promise
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shopsy') //pass the DB along with connection-URL
    .then(client=>{
        console.log("Connected");
        _DB = client.db();  //fetch DB
        callback();
     })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
     });
}


const getDB =()=>{
    if(_DB){
        return _DB;
    }
    throw "No Database Found";
}


exports.MongoConnection = MongoConnection;
exports.getDB = getDB;

And then import & use it into the App.js file like this.
const MongoConnection = require('./config/connection');  //import module
const PORT = 4000 ; //whatever you want to use

MongoConnection(()=>{

      app.listen(PORT, () => {
          console.log(`Database running & Listining on port: ${PORT}`)
      })

})

And if you want to get the the DB then do this.
const getdb = require('./config/connection').getDB; //import getDB module

const DB = getdb();  //returns you DB name in your case `shopsy`

Try this. It will work for sure.
N:B :- You dont even need to export your app.In any case if you import this module to any other module it will cause Circular-Dependency
