Can't connect to MongoClient using Node
i made a simple program to connect to my mongoDB database
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let db = null;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'chatbotdb';

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

app.use(jsonParser);
app.use(urlencodedParser);

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("This log is never shown.");

    db = client.db(dbName);
    
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running on: localhost:3000'); //this log is always shown


i was expecting to see the log of connection to mongoDB, i already have MongoDBCompass installed and my server is running

Please explain your problem in detail . Mention error if any .
i have checked your code , its working fine.

have you started the mongod server ?

The log of conection just doesn't show, but that's my first time using mongoDB, maybe i didn't connect properly, i opened the MongoDB Compass and clicked "connect" on the url 'mongodb://localhost:27017/', do i need an additional step to connect the server?

Download the community server from this url - https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community

i have downloaded the current version, it installed the mongoDBCompass i tried to use for connecting my server, do i need to create additional folders or maybe run something on the cmd in addition to connect?

@Mindfullofblanks, This might answer your query, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78687877/node-js-express-application-not-logging-mongodb-connection-status/78689128#78689128

You would have to show us the code of your corresponding handler function but my guess is that you never reach a call to res.send or res.json to name a few response sending functions.

i'm using updateData(objJson, function(result){
res.send(result);
}) and const updateData = function(objJson, callback){
const collection = db.collection('chatbot');
const code_current = objJson.code_current;
collection.updateOne({code_current: code_current}, {$set: objJson} , function(err, result){
assert.equal(null,err);
callback(result);
});
}

The node.js driver connects lazily, so you won't actually see any connection to the server until you do some operation that requires connecting to the server.
db = client.db(dbName) can be performed with the data available on the client side without connecting.
Try ping since that requires a response from the server.
